# Access key not working on CheckBox after applying style

Tags: .net, wpf, styles, access-keys

Ive applied some styling on `CheckBoxes` in my app to write default values to some its properties.

```
 <Style
        TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter
            Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Left" />
        <Setter
            Property="Margin"
            Value="2" />
        <Setter
            Property="MinHeight"
            Value="22" />
 </Style>
```

But that ruined the access keys, now `Content` looks like for example: _Is Active and not Is Active with access on ALT hold+I. How to make style work with access keys working too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it just now, VS'10, WPF 4.0, SP1. worked fine. Alt+I changed `checkbox` state. code for test:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter
            Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Left" />
        <Setter
            Property="Margin"
            Value="2" />
        <Setter
            Property="MinHeight"
            Value="22" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<CheckBox Content="_IsActive" />
```

Maybe you forgot to specify some aspects?

Or I don't understand something

Comment: ...may be there is something else making it ignoring access key....Thank you for check, i'll recheck all that when i'll be near that code.

Comment: ..By the way, there were problems with our custom styling. Thanks.

Comment: If this is not a secret, which lines of code changed the normal behavior?

Comment: Sure not..But that was my mistake..I had a style defined for combobox where i used textblock to show combo's text.